# The argument must be a React element, but you passed undefined

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am trying to use **ResponsiveContainer** from **recharts** in a react and getting this error.

> React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed undefined.

My Sample code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { ResponsiveContainer } from 'recharts';

function App() {
  return (
       <ResponsiveContainer>
       </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: At first, try to have a look what's exactly in the ResponsiveContainer variable. Perhaps you should use the default export instead of the named export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a chart inside the container. `ResponsiveContainer` is not designed to work on its own, and will throw the error you're seeing if there is no child component.

Here's the example from the [documentation](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/ResponsiveContainer):

```
<ResponsiveContainer width={700} height="80%">
  <AreaChart data={data}
    margin={{ top: 20, right: 30, left: 0, bottom: 0 }}>
    <XAxis dataKey="name" />
    <YAxis />
    <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
    <Tooltip />
    <ReferenceLine x="Page C" stroke="green" label="Min PAGE" />
    <ReferenceLine y={4000} label="Max" stroke="red" strokeDasharray="3 3" />
    <Area type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#8884d8" fill="#8884d8" />
  </AreaChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```